# jQuery onclick without 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

```
// Block class
function Block(id) {
    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click( function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
}
```

The console log outputs the HTML element that is clicked, which is not what I want. I would like to access the `Block` object associated to this element instead. How is this possible?

Comment: Use the arrow function? `() => {}`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the arrow function, which is newly defined in ES6.

> "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function
>   expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot
>   be used as constructors."

```
function Block(id) {
    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click( () => {
        console.log(this); // now this will be what it was outside of the anonymous function passed into .click
    });
}
```

Note that not all browsers have implemented this functionality. I believe it works in chrome but not IE (of course). So if you want to use this feature I would also suggest that you look at using a javascript transpiler (I would recommend Babel), which will convert your javascript to be compatible with specific browser versions. So after using babel on the above function the javascript will look something like this

```
function Block(id) {
    var objectReference = this;
    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click( function() {
        console.log(objectReference); 
    });
}
```

You could of course always just write your function like above and not need to use Babel. Babel is really only worth it if you want to ensure browser compatibility or if you plan on using more ES6 features.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to the ones posted is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function Block(id) {
    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click(console.log.bind(this));
}
```

This approach is nice as it doesn't require the extra context-saving variable.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are passing to the .click() method exists in the context of your element, and so `this` in that context refers to the element.  By saving the outer context in a variable you can access it inside your new context:

```
// Block class
function Block(id) {
    var self = this;  // here, this refers to Block()
    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click( function() {
        console.log(this); // here this refers to element
        console.log(self); // here self refers to Block()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the value of `this` in a variable outside the click handler:

```
function Block(id) {
    var self = this; //capture "this" in outside context

    this.element = $('<td>');
    $(this.element).click(function() {
        console.log(self);
    });
}
```